# Electromagnets and voltage

Tags: voltage, electromagnet

I'm thinking of getting two electromagnets.  On Amazon, it reads 24V 400N. What does that mean? Of course, it would be DC since that is what electromagnets are based on. I will use a simple series circuit.

Does 24V 400N mean it will exert 400 Newtons of force when I input 24 volts, or is 24 volts the maximum input voltage?

How would I power the TWO of these electromagnets in series? Should I use LiPos, alkalines (AA or 9 volts)?

Comment: Provide links to the objects in question.  400N is likely the output force at point blank range with 24V applied to a specific test rig.  To run two in series at full power, you'd use 48V.

Comment: (1) "*Of course, it would be DC since that is what electromagnets are based on.*" AC electromagnets exist. AC relay coils, for example. (2) "*I will use a simple series circuit.*" What else would you use? (3) "*How would I power ...*" We don't know. You haven't provided the datasheet link. Welcome to EE.SE.

Answer (score 3):

24V is the voltage of the coil. You can put a lower voltage to reduce the strength, but you cannot give a higher voltage.

400N is the force to which it will "Hold".

Given the electromagnet has a stated force in Newton, it can be assumed it is the type that holds the door, which has a magnetic circuit that is broken up where you place a magnetic material (a piece of steel for example).

Electromagnets of the type that are used to hold the doors have strong force when their electromagnetic circuit is "closed", which means when you have a piece of metal (which is magnetic) directly in contact with it. As soon as the electromagnetic circuit is open, even of a few millimeters, the force drops significantly.

Comment: https://e-magnetsuk.com/product/round-electromagnets-24-volt/ "a gap of only 0.1mm will result in a drop off in performance of around 90%. This includes paints and non-magnetic coatings."

Comment: May I ask how I would power two of these electromagnets? AA and 9V batteries have pretty high internal resistance, so should I use two Lithium-Polymer batteries each at 11.1 Volts?

Comment: Usually, those magnet takes a decent amount of current. A battery wouldn't last long if you use it in steady-state. You can have 2x 9V battery in series. Don't go LiPo unless you have low-voltage cutoff protection otherwise your battery may take fire.